# Long time of first execution of sql query on firebid 2.5.1 server

Tags: laravel, firebird, firebird2.5

After connecting to the database, the first execution of the query is very slow:

```
------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 16ms
Execute time = 1s 969ms
```

But the next execution is pretty fast

```
------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 15ms
Execute time = 297ms
```

After reconnect it's slow again

```
------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 62ms
Execute time = 1s 953ms
```

Can I solve this problem. I think it's related to the preparation of the query

Comment: please show us the what you tried. show some code you have worked out. it would help us to help you

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why are you still using Firebird 2.5.1? It is 8 years old and has known security vulnerabilities. The last 2.5.x is 2.5.9 from this year. And latest overall version is 3.0.4.

Comment: As to your problem, without the necessary DDL, the actual statement and its plan, it is not really possible to tell (nor even guess) as to what may cause this except maybe uncached reads vs cached reads.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm going to install a newer version of FB.
I checked a little and I think that it takes some time for the server to compile the query, check for authorization for procedures and tabels.
If I am executing the query for the first time after connecting to the database, the server compiles and executes the query. The next time the query is only executed, it uses the compiled version.
Can I somehow solve this problem. For example, use a compiled version of the query (procedure) to make it faster?
Have newer versions improved anything in this aspect?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 2.5.1 has the notorious index bug that makes their databases incompatible with all other Firebird versions. He can not update server without backup-restore cycle.

Comment: Show full performance information, including Fetches From Cache and Fetches From Disc. Also, show the statements themselves and the query PLAN.

Comment: @Arioch'The All the more reason to upgrade

Comment: Your assumption that the server retains a compiled statement is unlikely. Firebird doesn't retain a global cache of compiled plans. That only happens per prepared statement, and as you seem to be executing through a query tool, it is unlikely that it is reusing the prepared statement. The difference is likely more one of caching (metadata cache, page buffers and filesystem caches).

Comment: ....and poor design of database/queries might requires "natural scan" on some tables, which in turn would require the whole of those databases to be cached in, before query can go (inefficiently, but still). He very probably is seeing cache warming up effect, but it may be just the surfacing of deeper problems. @Wiesiek the said compilation in SQL terms is called "preparation" and it was made in 16ms in your case. Unless you honna re-execute that query 100 times a seconf or more it is not the problem. Also the connection to server might be long, but u say you measured after-connection workings

Comment: I think that this article "The life cycle of a Firebird SQL statement" (https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/general/doc_381) explain what I mean.